# read changes stdout from unbuffered to line buffered in canonical mode

Tags: c, getchar, termios

When I use this piece of code in canonical mode:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static struct termios newt;
static struct termios oldt;

static void kb_fini(void)
{
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
}

void kb_init(void)
{
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= (tcflag_t)~(ICANON | ECHO | ISIG);
    newt.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    newt.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    atexit(kb_fini);
}

int main(void)
{
    int c;

    kb_init();
    printf("Press q ");
    c = getchar();
    if (c == 'q') {
        printf("q was pressed\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am able to read "Press q " in console before pressing `q`

Switching to `read`:

```
int main(void)
{
    char c;

    kb_init();
    printf("Press q ");
    read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
    if (c == 'q') {
        printf("q was pressed\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Doesn't show "Press q " until `q` is pressed.

Why is this?

Comment: The standard I/O package knows what is happening and coordinates things so that the pending output to standard output is flushed before invoking the read operation.  The `read()` system call doesn't know or care about what's going on with STDOUT_FILENO.  If you're going to mix the two modes, make sure you `fflush(stdout);` or `fflush(0);` before using `read()`.

Comment: My bet is, that stdout is line-buffered by default. Try `fflush(stdout)` just after `printf()`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, makes sense, thank you!, Does mixing the two modes have well defined behaviour?

Comment: @vlp, thank you, yes, I know `fflush` fixes the problem, my question was why the different behaviour between `read` and `getchar`

Comment: "Does mixing the two modes have well defined behaviour?" I would not bet on it. Even iff it does, it is bad design style and problemating to maintain, e.g. if you read the code some time later and try to understand what is going on. Ist there actually a good reason not to stick with just one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I observed in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241929/read-changes-stdout-from-unbuffered-to-line-buffered-in-canonical-mode#comment56225859_34241929), the standard I/O package knows what is happening and coordinates things so that the pending output to standard output (`stdout`) is flushed before invoking the read operation on standard input (`stdin`) — at least when the output and input are an 'interactive device', aka terminal.  Note that the synchronization is not actually mandated by the C standard, but most implementations provide it.

The `read()` system call doesn't know or care about what's going on with the standard I/O package.  It has no access to any of the file streams, nor to any of the data private to those streams (such as buffered output).  Therefore, it cannot ensure that pending standard output is flushed before it attempts to read the input.

If you're going to mix the two modes, make sure you `fflush(stdout);` or `fflush(0);` before using `read()`.

> Does mixing the two modes have well defined behaviour?

It depends on how you mix them.  If you use `stdout` for output and `STDIN_FILENO` for input, there's no problem beyond the lack of synchronization by default.  If you try to mix `stdout` operations with operations directly on `STDOUT_FILENO`, or `stdin` operations with operations directly on `STDIN_FILENO`, then you are in for a world of hurt, in general.  Don't try that as you value your own (or your users') sanity.  Amongst other problems, the standard I/O library can buffer ahead and the file descriptor functions won't be able to see what standard I/O already read.  Conversely, on writing, the standard I/O library will buffer and the file descriptor I/O won't.

Comment: An interesting read (libc specific) [on mixing modes](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Stream_002fDescriptor-Precautions.html), [buffering](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Stream-Buffering.html) and [flushing](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Flushing-Buffers.html).